# cron 経由で実行した PHP スクリプトからのメール送信ができない

Tags: php, cron

ローカル環境ではうまくいったのですが、Xserver上で実行したところ、デバッグ用のメールが、while構文の中までメールの送信、かつ、コードの実行ができたのですが、while構文の後からコードの実行ができなくなっております。

初歩的なところかもしれませんが、理由がお気づきの方、ご指導をお願いします。

```
<?php

 // ファイルを変数に格納
//$filename = '../log/log.txt';
$filename = './log.txt';

// fopenでファイルを開く（'r'は読み込みモードで開く）
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');



// whileで行末までループ処理
while (!feof($fp)) {

  // fgetsでファイルを読み込み、変数に格納
  $txt = fgets($fp);

  // ファイルを読み込んだ変数を出力
  $log = $log.$txt;

}
 // fcloseでファイルを閉じる
fclose($fp);


// メール情報
$mailto = "XXXX@gmail.com"; // 宛先のメールアドレス
$subject = "Daily log from XXXX.biz";
$content = $log;
$mailfrom = "From:info@xn--XXXX.biz"; // From:送信元のメールアドレス(サーバパネルで設定したやつ)


// メール送信処理
$result = mail($mailto,$subject,$content,$mailfrom);

// メール送信処理結果出力
if($result){
    echo "送信成功!";
    $fp = fopen($filename , 'r+');
    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

//2番目の引数のファイルサイズを0にして空にする
ftruncate($fp,0);

flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);

}else{
    $content = "送信失敗";
    $result = mail($mailto,$subject,$content,$mailfrom);
}
?>
```

Comment: ソースを見ただけだと私にはわからなかったですね。。ちなみにPHPのエラーなどは出ていますか？

Comment: コードが実行できないと読み取れますが、具体的にどういう状況ですか？ところで`mail()`を直接使うことはあまりないのですが、その性質上そのままではマルチバイト文字が扱えなかったり、本文各行が70文字を超えるといけなかったりするようです。[マニュアル](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples)にはwordwrapで超える行を自動的に改行する例などが掲載されていますが……

Comment: ファイル内に日本語などのマルチバイト文字が入っている場合、mail関数ではうまく送信できない可能性があります。また、対象のPHPバージョンはいくつを想定していますか？

Comment: 皆様、コメントありがとうございます。PHPエラーはなく、$contents ="test"としたときも、while構文直後からうまくいきません。(昨晩、実は、while構文の中にうっかりmail関数を書き、大量のメールを送ってしまい、１時間ほどxserverさんに怒られ止められましたので、whil構文までは動いてます。)

Comment: 「$result = mail($mailto,$subject,$content,$mailfrom);」のあとに「var_dump($result);」を入れて、結果が同ななっているかを教えてもらえますか。結果が「false」となっている場合、xserver側でメール送信が制限されている可能性があるため、1度問い合わせされることをおすすめします。そもそも送信エラーになったのに、「else」の中で再度メール送信しようとしても、あまり意味ないと思うのですが、いかがでしょう。

Comment: これは回答ではなく提案ですが、ファイル読み込みをfile_get_contents(__DIR__."/log.txt")に置き換えてメールが送るところまで問題が出づらいようにしてはどうでしょうか。またログに日本語が使われているならmb_sendmailやそのほかの手段をとったほうがよいです。

Comment: Koki様、ありがとうございます。file_get_contents("./log.txt", true)で開いてみたところ、WEB上で実行すると問題ないのですが、cronに当該phpファイルを実行させるとfileがみつからないというエラーが発生します。。。cronからの実行と通常の実行では参照ファイルのpathがかわるのでしょうか。。。

Comment: // メール情報
$mailto = "XXX@gmail.com"; // 宛先のメールアドレス
$subject = "Daily log from XXX.biz";
$content = file_get_contents('log.txt', true);
$mailfrom = "From:info@XXX.biz";  // From:送信元のメールアドレス(サーバパネルで設定したやつ)
上記にて動くようになりましたが、エラーがでます。
PHP Warning:  fopen(log.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
もしご存知の方いらっしゃればお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron のカレントディレクトリは実行ユーザのホームディレクトリになります。

そのため

```
$filename = './log.txt';
```

この参照が間違っている可能性があります。
問題なければ絶対パスで指定するか、事前にcdでディレクトリ移動しておく必要があります。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、ファイル名を修正したところできました。（また新たな問題がでましたが。）ご指導ありがとうございました。